# Upgrading Magento 2.2.6 and want to upgrade to Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.1

I am using Magento 2.2.6 Enterprise version and the site is live now.

I want to upgrade my store to the latest version of Magento which is 2.4.1. My store has many customizations in code and theme aspects. Some of the customizations are checkout, login, sales, product, pricing, and finance-related.

Except for the order placement, product and pricing, financial management, order processing, etc are handled by different systems like the ERP and the CRM. Now, I want to know will all, or any of these customizations be affected when I upgrade to Magento 2.4.1?
Should I have to make any code changes according to Magento 2.4.1?

Please clarify my question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a website that shows the differences between Magento 2.3 and Magento 2.4 https://meetanshi.com/blog/magento-2-3-release/

**However**, there's simply no way to tell whether you would need to make updates or not until you do the migration. Professionally speaking and ideally, you should have a test server where you would

1. Test the migration
2. Debug the errors
3. Once all errors are debugged and modules are stable, you move that to your live-server

But no one can accurately predict or tell you, with absolutely certainty, which modules wouldn't work unless they, themselves, try it as well which will require you to give them all the code and they'll repeat the aforementioned process.

Comment: Can you please give an idea what are the changes in Magento 2.3 or higher versions when compared to Magento 2.2.6? I am not asking about which are the modules will work or not. I want a clarification whether if I have customized a core functionality, the current module developed for Magento 2.2.6 will work on Magento 2.4 or not. Please clarify

Comment: @VigneshS Ive updated my answer. Mark it as the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: @Zyzzx, we have a similar situation but identified and separated customizations to separate modules, what is the recommended approach to test the upgrade in a VM and in a non-production site?